# How to get input key in transform or transformIndexHtml in Vite or Rollup?

Tags: vite, rollup, rollupjs

I want to make a Vite plugin for file routers. I can't find the specific plugin in Awesome Vite and Rollup Awesome. Or maybe I am too lazy to curated one-by-one.

My problem is Rollup Input can give a name for the file in `input` option. It would also be use to pairing output to targeted entry file. But, how could I get this current transformation name in `transform` by Rollup or `transformIndexHtml` by Vite?

Here are example of code:

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react-swc'
import Inspect from 'vite-plugin-inspect'
import process from "process"

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  build: {
    input: {
      "about/know-me": "template/default.html",
      "about/company": "template/default.html",
    },
    output: [
      {
        name: "about/know-me",
        entryFilename: "about/know-me.html",
      },
      {
        name: "about/company",
        entryFilename: "about/company.html",
      },
    ],
  },

  plugins: [
    Inspect({
      build: true,
      outputDir: ".vite-inspect.local",
    }),

    {
      transform: {
        order: "pre",
        handler: (html, ctx) => {
          // 1. get current input name such as "about/know-me"
          // 2. replace %SCRIPT_SCR% to be "srx/about/know-me.tsx"
        return html;
        },
      },
    },
    react(),
  ],

  root: process.cwd(),
});
```

The above code are example what I want to achieve, If I can get the `input` key name, I could replace the `%SCRIPT_SRC%` inside html file. In full Idea, the plugin would indexing all script file ended with `.page.tsx`, and create the page `.html` from it. At the same time, it would also store a temporary config base on the file name, so I could call `config[name].script`. This was the idea.

In short, how could I get current in compiling input file, synchronized inside `transform` function, OR asynchronized via hooks?

What I want to achieve is this plugin:

- https://github.com/FarhanMS123/vite-mpa-framework-files-router/blob/dda1c2192c66cf716b51e662392a7c6fe768db2f/src/plugin/files-router.ts#L69